# Can't get WiFi Payloads to iPad using Apple Configurator

Tags: ipad, apple-configurator

I have 400 iPads I need to prep and am having a couple issues. I was hoping somebody could give me a bit of advice..

**Question**

- How can I verify the WiFi payloads are copied to the iPad?

**Background**

- Apple Configurator 1.5
- I received a backup config from the customer
- I also received their settings in case the restore didn’t work.
- Of the settings I’m concentrating on two to verify the restore worked, or a manual config and prepare worked. Those are verifying an app was installed, and wifi payloads.
- When I restore using the supplied *.iosdevicebackup file neither the app or the wifi settings are on the iPad
- I configured iTunes for the customers account -> downloaded the app -> imported into the Apps tab of the Configurator program and now get that loaded, but I can’t confirm the wifi payloads.
- have 3 wifi payloads configured in the setup tab -> wifi section. 2 are for the customers wifi and the 3rd is for our in-house wifi just for sanity’s sake. Each are configured with ssid and WPA / password, but when the IPad is restarted after the prepare I would assume I would see all 3 networks and the iPad would connect to our in-house network automatically as it's the only one available. But I only see a list of available networks, and I’m asked for a password when I try to connect to our in-house one. I thought that was what the payload was for.
- I also tried making a profile and setting the wifi payloads up there, same result.
- I’ve been speaking with the local apple store, and while polite and professional, not much help..
- When I try to do a manual prepare my settings -> Restore value is Don't resort backup. If I have that set to the backup I received I get an error when trying to customize the device at the end of the update.
- I also tried only 1 wifi payload, our in-house WiFi. Same results. I'm asked for a login / password when I try to connect.

Comment: this can be closed.  The WiFi networks were mixed case.  I missed it.........multiple times..:(

Comment: +1 on the question and the answer. Thanks for helping document what was happening for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WiFi networks were mixed case which caused the confusion and problems.